# How to open a dropdown and close another dropdown with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have these two dropdowns & when the one is open the other doesn't close.
I want to use if-else statements but i'm not very familiar with JavaScript code.

```
$(".dropdown").on( "click", function() {
    $(".v-dropdown").slideToggle();
    return false;
});


$(".dropdown2").on( "click", function() {
    $(".v-dropdown2").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a  class="dropdown" data-hover="title">title</a>
<ul class="v-dropdown2">
<li><a href="#" data-hover="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="4">4</a></li>
</ul>

<li>
<a class="dropdown2" data-hover="title">title</a>
<ul class="v-dropdown2">
<li><a href="#" data-hover="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="4">4</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the `HTML` elements that you are referring to in your js code?

Comment: Even better, setup an example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give them the same class, i.e. `dropdown` and `v-dropdown`, and the code would be

```
$(".dropdown").on( "click", function() {
    var current_dropdown = $(this).next(".v-dropdown");
    $(".v-dropdown").not(current_dropdown).slideUp();
    current_dropdown.slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

If you don't want to change the classes you can use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Try this

```
$(".dropdown").on( "click", function() {
    var current_dropdown = $(".v-dropdown");
    $("[class^=v-dropdown]").not(current_dropdown).slideUp()
    current_dropdown.slideToggle();
    return false;
});


$(".dropdown2").on( "click", function() {
    var current_dropdown = $(".v-dropdown2");
    $("[class^=v-dropdown]").not(current_dropdown).slideUp()
    current_dropdown.slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What solution did you try? Did you get any error in the console? What didn't work exactly?

Comment: I saw your HTML and find an error in my first proposal, change the `find()` function for `next()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the second example you gave. It helped with the closing of the dropdowns. But when i have only one open dropdown and try to close it it opens again.

Comment: You're welcome ;) But, just for the record, the first example would be better, because you abstract the `dropdown` and `v-dropdown` classes and you could add some other dropdowns with the same html structure without changing the javascript code.

Comment: Hi again. Can you also tell me how to keep open the dropdown when i change pages?

Comment: I think that could be helpful if you create a new question

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea. Give all drop down's the same class. Hide all drop downs on click, and only slide down the drop down clicked;

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() { // <-- all drop downs should have the class .dropdown
    $('.v-dropdown').slideUp(); // <-- all sections to slide should have the class .v-dropdown
    $(this).find('.v-dropdown').slideDown(); // slide down only this element
});
```

This assumes your html structure has `.v-dropdown` nested within `.dropdown`. If it is not, then adjust the selector to use something like `.next()` or something else to find the related drop down to the clicked element instead of `.find()`.

**UPDATE**

[Here's a very basic fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a522txhp/) of the funcitonality. Your HTML was invalid so I've modified it to work.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
    var slide_el = $(this).next().find('.v-dropdown');

    // don't slide up if clicking on the already visible element
    if (!slide_el.is(':visible')) {
      $('.v-dropdown').slideUp();
    }
    slide_el.slideToggle(); // only slide clicked element
  });

});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  a {
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #444;
  }
}

.v-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top">
  <li class="dropdown" data-hover="title">title</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="v-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="top">
  <li class="dropdown" data-hover="title">title</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="v-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hover="4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: edited my answer - please note the CSS is in SCSS format - copied from JS Fiddle, but that's not pertinent to the answer really.

Answer (score 1):

You can just slideToggle() both of the dropdowns on click event.

```
$(".dropdown").on( "click", function() {
    $(".v-dropdown").slideToggle();
    $(".v-dropdown2").slideToggle();
    return false;
});


$(".dropdown2").on( "click", function() {
    $(".v-dropdown2").slideToggle();
    $(".v-dropdown").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

So when you press one the other one will slideToggle too.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to close the x dropdown when you press y dropdown.
The snippet above does what you desire.